# Converting from Bytes to String doesn't work // Python/Scapy

Tags: python, byte, scapy, decoding

I've got some trouble by converting from datatype bytes to a string.
I'm generating a dns query with scapy, capture the response and I'm now trying to work with this response.

Here the code for generating and capturing and how the result looks like:

```
from scapy.all import *

dns = IP()/UDP()/DNS()
dns[IP].dst = "194.25.0.70"
dns["DNS Question Record"].qname = "12354987.xxxx.xxxx.de"
dns["DNS Question Record"].qtype = 35

ans, unans = sr(dns) 
ans.summary()
```

Output:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.


Received 4 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
IP / UDP / DNS Qry "b'12354987.xxxx.xxxx.de.'"  ==> IP / UDP / DNS Ans "b'\x00\n\x00\x00\x01s\x08SIPS+D2T\x00\x05_sips\x04_tcp\x0c12354987\x07xxxx\x0bxxxx\x02de\x00'"
```

This works good. Next step is to extract the relevant parts of the response:

```
naptr = ans[0][1][UDP][DNS][DNSRR].rdata
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\n\x00\x00\x01s\x08SIPS+D2T\x00\x05_sips\x04_tcp\x0c12354987\x07xxxxy\x0bxxxx\x02de\x00'
```

I've tried to convert this type of bytes with .decode(), .decode('utf-8'), .decode('ascii'), with str(naptr) and some functiones found in the scapy documentation. But noting really works.
Everytime I get the same result:
`'\x00\n\x00\x00\x01s\x08SIPS+D2T\x00\x05_sips\x04_tcp\x0c12354987\x07xxxx\x0bxxxx\x02de\x00'`

Do you have any ideas or is here anyone who worked already with scapy?
Thanks a lot.

BR
Dennis

Comment: You understand that DNS is a binary protocol, don't you? Why do you think that should be convertible to a string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. 
I mean - capturing a DNS lookup with wireshark also displays the response without b'\x00\n\x00..... nslookup on command line too. 
So I thought there should be a way to do it with python and scapy.

Comment: Wireshark parses the packet according to the DNS protocol, and converts it to readable strings.

Comment: In particular, a hostname is not represented as a simple string. Each component is a length byte followed by that many characters, and it also has a way to refer back to previous components as a simple form of compression (since domain suffixes are often repeated).

Comment: Ok - understand. 
But is there no way to parse it in python like wireshark do it?

Answer (score 0):

The binary data that you provided seems to represent a DNS NAPTR record. In this case, you may need to interpret the structure of the NAPTR record and extract the relevant information. The NAPTR record format includes various fields like order, preference, flags, service, regex, and replacement.

```
from scapy.all import *

# Create DNS query
dns = IP()/UDP()/DNS()
dns[IP].dst = "194.25.0.70"
dns["DNS Question Record"].qname = "12354987.xxxx.xxxx.de"
dns["DNS Question Record"].qtype = 35

# Send DNS query and receive response
ans, unans = sr(dns) 

# Print summary of the response
ans.summary()

# Extract the NAPTR record
naptr = ans[0][1][UDP][DNS][DNSRR].rdata

# Assuming the format of the NAPTR record is something like:
# HHHH16sHHHHHHHHHs

# Unpack the binary data
decoded_data = struct.unpack("!HHHH16sHHHHHHHHHs", naptr)

# Extract individual fields
order, preference, flags, service, regex, replacement = decoded_data

# Convert bytes to string for certain fields
service_str = service.decode('utf-8')
regex_str = regex.decode('utf-8')
replacement_str = replacement.decode('utf-8')

# Print the extracted information
print(f"Order: {order}")
print(f"Preference: {preference}")
print(f"Flags: {flags}")
print(f"Service: {service_str}")
print(f"Regex: {regex_str}")
print(f"Replacement: {replacement_str}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. 
I tried it but get following error: 

error: unpack requires a buffer of 43 bytes

My python knowledge is not deep enough to cleary understand what happend here. Online documentation doesn't help me..